# iPhone Accelerometer direction

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, direction

I am developing an application in which iPhone will play different sounds when moved (sword).
I want to know when iPhone has moved left, right, up or down (sword movement).
How can I implement this?
I was testing the accelerometer and wrote this code, but it returns the same values if moved left or right. How can I know in which direction is the iPhone moved?

Code:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    double const kThreshold = 1.0;

    if (fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold) {
        NSLog(@"X+");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left and right both use acceleration.x

I'm not sure which is which but one is negative x and the other is positive x.

Same for up/down and back/forth.

They all use the same axis (x, y or z) but one direction is positive change and the other is negative change.

By using fabsf you are removing the negative side of the movement.

You need something like...

```
if (acceleration.x > kThreshold) {
    NSLog(@"X+");
} else if (acceleration.x < kThreshold * -1) {
    NSLog(@"X-");
}
```

or something instead.

Comment: Nope, it gives me positive direction if I move iPhone left or right.

Comment: Yup, that's because you are using fabsf.  fabsf gives the absolute value of x.  fabsf(10) = 10. But also fabsf(-10) = 10 also.

Comment: Well that was stupid of me not to think of that fabs removes negative value. Thx!

Comment: I will accept your answer in 3 minutes, stackoverflow doesn't let me now.

Comment: Well that doesn't work very well, it is random.
Can you please test it and suggest a better answer?

Comment: How do you mean it is random?

Comment: Sometimes when I move it left it generates both sounds, sometimes just the left sound, sometimes right sound. When I move it right it's the same.
Code:
http://pastebin.com/ENhBscPA

Comment: Well, it depends how slowly/quickly you move. The accelerometer does not measure movement direction.  It measures acceleration direction. This includes deceleration too.  If you quickly jerk to the left and equally quickly come to a stop then you will trigger the left and right sounds. If you need a different approach I guess you will need to test some or come up with a way around it.

Comment: Equally, if you slowly move to the left and then quickly stop it then you will only trigger the right movement sound.  I suggest logging out the acceleration to console to see what effect the movements are having.

Comment: Do you know some way to calibrate this better?

Comment: I've never done anything like this with the accelerometer. You could try to store movement speed as a vector. Then instead of using the straight acceleration you can use the accel to add/subtract from the movement vector and use the vector to play the sounds instead. Or put a minimum timer on when sounds will play or something.