# Get direction of device motion by using accelerometer in ios device

Tags: ios, accelerometer

I want to get direction of the device motion by using accelerometer. I tried method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018770/how-to-determine-the-direction-of-a-iphone-shake) as below :-

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)aceler {

    if (fabsf(aceler.x) > 1.5)
    {
        shake = YES;
        NSTimeInterval myInterval = .75;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:myInterval target:self selector:@selector(endShake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        return;
    }

    if(shake)
    {
        totalG += aceler.x;
    }
}

- (void) endShake {
    shake = NO;
    int direction;
    if (totalG isLessThan 0) direction = 1;
    if(totalG isGreaterThan 0) direction = -1;
    [self changePageByShake:direction];
    totalG = 0;
}
```

But it's not giving accurate results. Is there any standard way to get the direction of the device ?

Note :- This is different from orientation of the device.

Comment: Can you check this one?
it may help
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/basic-sensors-in/9781449309480/ch04.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Accelerometer direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439915/iphone-accelerometer-direction)